# How to install both TortoiseSVN version 1.6 and 1.7 together in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, svn, tortoise-svn

Currently installing 1.7 will remove 1.6.

Since svn 1.7 is not stable for all svn server (one of my server keep getting errors on authentication as my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798977/what-happens-to-netbeans)), I want to use both Tortoise 1.7 and 1.6 together.

Is it possible? If yes, please share me how. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What features in 1.7 do you need?  Seem strange they would change anything about the authentication process.  Do you know versions the server that causing your prolems is running vs the server that works with 1.7?

Comment: @Ramhound I love the swept-out `.svn` folders in 1.7; now no more thousands of .svn folders to me. And the new UI of TortoiseSVN too - more convinient to use for me.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know the svn server version - is there a way to know from svn client?

Comment: for http repo you *can* see in server response (see source of any repo-page), for svn+ssh repo `ssh user@host svnserve --version` or `...svnadmin --version...`

Comment: @LazyBadger I tried as my above screenshot but failed to call `ssh`. Any ideas?

Comment: if **this** ubuntu-host is different from SVN-server, can't see reasons to use additional hop in chain. And - your shell on CC-server may be non-interactive... ask admin about version? Or login by putty from your Win-box

Comment: and mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798977/what-happens-to-netbeans problem is problem not SVN|SVN-server 1.7, but old NB with WC-NG

Answer (score 5):

You can not use (have installed) both TSVN at the same time.

But client and server version (at least in 1.6-1.7 pair) are unrelated - due to minimal changes on server-side you can use 1.7 client with 1.6 servers

Comment: I know that already. It would be just more lovely to have both 1.6 & 1.7 on my machine so as to get used with 1.7 early.

Comment: There are a lot of quirks you would face installing TSVN 1.6 and 1.7 in parallel, so the decision by the Tortoise team is understandable. I don't think that the UI will have a lot of changes, the changes are more in the working copy format (== file system), and this you will never touch in any way.